# How can I get the standard deviation for this kind of data?

Tags: standard-deviation

I have data which looks like the following, only larger:

```
               Frequency
Indicators  (1)    (2)    (3)    mean
    1        4     140    27     2.13
    2        5     126    34     2.18
    3        40    66     46     2.04
    4        5     108    57     2.31
    5        2     113    57     2.32
```

I need to get its standard deviation because we were asked to perform hypothesis testing to it with another data which is of the same kind, just from different sample. BTW, the data above is from a population of hospital personnel (as in I have the data of whole population) and the weights means

```
3 - fully implemented
2 - partially implemented
1 - not implemented
```

I have to test if its mean has a significant difference to the mean of responses of patients in the hospital. I am asking about the standard deviation because I just saw that I need the variance in the z-test

Comment: Why are you trying to do a z-test in this situation?

Comment: the researcher asks if there is a significant difference between the extent of implementation of waste management program in the specific hospital as perceived by the hospital personnel and by the patients. So I think difference in means?

Comment: Does it really make sense to say that one "fully implemented" and one "not implemented" is actually identical to two "partially implemented"s? I would hesitate to do that (treat the ordinal scale as linear scores), but even if you're confident that's what you want, you need to also consider whether you should be dealing with  those 5 indicators as a multivariate response rather than individual univariate ones

Comment: I'm not the researcher here, I was simply asked to answer the statements of the problem namely: a) what is the profile of the respondents b) what is the extent of implementation of waste management program in the hospital as perceived by the personnel and by the patients c) is there a significant difference in the perception of the hospital staff and the patients

Comment: and there are about 57 different indicators, should I just treat them individually?

Comment: If you weren't asked to use means I wouldn't use means here. Whether they should be treated individually (possibly with some correction for multiple-testing) or collectively depends on what the researcher is really trying to find out; that's a question got the researcher. If it's a real problem I'd be asking them what they really need to know, but I'd be trying to explain the advantages of the multivariate approach. (Is this work for a course? "I was simply asked to answer the statements of the problem" sounds like this is an assignment)

Comment: Nope. Its hard to explain but here in our country (well, not generally), most statistics teachers don't really know what they're teaching. Actually, this is a Masters Research by our neighbor, and even she admits that she don't know how to do research, she only does this to fulfill the requirements of the degree, which I have no doubt she'll pass, since getting a Masters here is not that difficult compared to other institutions.

Comment: I, meanwhile, is just someone who finished BS Math and have a bit of idea about doing research, but after studying in the web, I realized most of what I learned in college is wrong, or not sufficient for true research. However, looking at how easy it is to finish a research here, I don't think teachers are that strict regarding the accuracy of the research a well as the techniques used

Comment: It's just that I'm very critical of my work, not wanting to just do something which is acceptable to them, I want it to be acceptable to myself too. Also, I accepted this job because it pays a lot here :)

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying, I think it will make it easier for people to give suggestions. If you want to compare two sets of counts in ordered categories there are a number of simple things that would likely be accepted, and a number of only slightly more complex things that would use more of the information in the data.